# How to check if column just added to google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a bit of code I want to run if the user just added a new column to the current google spreadsheet (i want to copy over formatting to the new column).

I think I need to use the onEdit(e) trigger, but I'm not sure how to tell if the a column was added or not before running that code.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to memorize the 'state' of your sheet and check on each edit if a column has been added.
This simple code does it, you should assign the function to an `OnEdit`  installable trigger (goto resources > current script triggers > add new trigger)

```
function CheckColumns() {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet()
    var numcol = sh.getMaxColumns()  
    var formertest = ScriptProperties.getProperty('lastTest')
      if(formertest!=numcol){
Logger.log('change has occured ...')   

// ... do what you want to do

  ScriptProperties.setProperties({'lastTest': numcol}, true);   
}
}
```

to see if it works simply view the logger. note that it will ask for authorization to access the script properties.